# Aternative to Dyescape

Tags: kotlin

I've used [Arrow Optics](https://arrow-kt.io/learn/quickstart/) (check below in the page) for some time with Gradle because at some point I had to stop using the plugin provided by [Dyescape](https://github.com/Dyescape/kotlin-maven-symbol-processing). The team at Dyescape was always great at following up with bugs, but at some point there were apparently no more updates for it. For some of my current projects, it would be interesting to be able to use Arrow Optics in Maven. However, without the Dyescape plugin there doesn't seem to be an alternative to use arrow optics and generate code without other than with Gradle and the KSP plugin.

Does anyone have any idea on which other plugin or other alternative form there may be to keep using `arrow-kt:arrow-optics` in Maven projects?

If you are curious about this, some of the projects that I had to move to Gradle can be found [here](https://github.com/jesperancinha/jeorg-kotlin-test-drives/tree/main/jeorg-kotlin-arrow-optics). I love Gradle, I think it's a great package manager, but I do have some situations where we need to use Maven that go beyond my reach.